# inheritance i laravel :Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance

this is my parent class  which is a user class that has the main crud operations

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;    //<----------- Here


class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;



    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->model::all();
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }

}
```

this is my child class which is one of my user roles , it have the same crud operation but it need some more functinality

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Teacher;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

class TeacherController extends UserController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = Teacher::class;
    }
}
```

when I try to access the route i get this error :  Class name must be a valid object or a string

at :

```
        $users = $this->model::all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems my Laravel project used old cached routes. Just run

```
 php artisan route:clear
```

from time to time before debugging anything.